# How to view the actual data in a SQL Differential backup file?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a method to view the actual data inside a differential backup file. I have searched on SO and Google but could not find anything useful. Perhaps I am using the wrong keywords.

I have found many articles like this;
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/view-the-contents-of-a-backup-tape-or-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16 and although this has some useful data, it does not let me view the actual data that has been changed since last full backup.

Possible solutions:

- Restore a differential backup without the full backup. But I don't see how this is possible.
- Use a query or sproc to view the contents of the backup file, much like the summary data is extracted in the example in above link.
- Run a query on the running database that will show the data that will be included in the next differential backup

Is any of these possible? If not, are there any other things I can try?

ps. Does not have to be a full view of all data, I could query specific tables if that's the only option.

Using SQL Server 2016

Thanks for any assistance!

Edit. As Martin Smith pointed out in the comments a differential backup on a SQL database differs from a files differential backup, also including rows that have no changes, thus I need to a new strategy.

Basically I need to know all rows that have been changed since a specific time. So I'm thinking about making a full backup and after a specific time, restore this into a new database and then somehow compare both databases by using a query.

Comment: If you're only concerned with some tables perhaps CDC (change data capture) might be useful?

Comment: You probably have the wrong idea about what a differential backup contains. It doesn't just contain the changed data. The data file is divided up into 64KB units called extents. There is a bitmap indicating if any of the data at all in that 64KB unit has changed and if so the whole extent is included in the differential backup. This is very likely to include a lot of rows that have not been changed along with the changed ones. It may also contain pages from different tables to the changed one in the case of mixed extents.

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin-smith, I did not know that. I assumed only the rows that had changes in them would be included, just like only the files that have changed would be included in a regular files differential backup. Seems I will need to change my strategy.

Comment: ApexSQL Backup is quite good for this kind of thing